# How to show options bar bottom of the page in swift?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a navigation controller embedded in a tab bar controller and I am using a table view on this page. I want to hide the tab bar and show options at the bottom of the page while editing the table view.

I can start and stop editing by a bar button item. I can hide tab bar but I couldn't show options to take actions for selected items of the table view.

I hide tab bar with this code but I am not sure that I should hide first. Maybe I should transform the bar.

```swift
tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
```

For example, these screenshots are from the photos app of the iPhone. In the first screenshot, the tab bar is showing. When the select button is clicked, options are showing like from the second screenshot.

tab bar is showing

[image]

options is showing

[image]

Comment: Do you need to show the bottom bar on Select button tap?

Comment: Also clarify how the selection logic works with selection in each collectionView.

Comment: Yes, I just need bottom bar which includes options such as delete. I have no problem with select button.

Comment: I use these lines to selectable table view
tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)

Comment: Add the code of CustomCell here.

Answer (score 0):

Idea : You can place a view with option button at bottom of of your View Controller and initially give height 0 and make view hidden. When your Tab bar become hidden/ image select  just simply make height of the view as tab bar height and make your view visible. Like following images.

[image: When Tab bar Visible, (I did not change height here, but you can)]
[image: When tab bar Hidden]

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I think there should be a formal way to do this because most of apps have this property.